# Inconsistency in Cassava documentation vs installed package on my system

Tags: haskell, csv

Today, I installed (via cabal) Haskell's cassava library for working with .csv files. According to the documentation (http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.1.0.1/docs/Data-Csv.html), the type header for decode is

```
decode :: FromRecord a => ByteString -> Either String (Vector a)
```

When I go to use it, the result makes no sense:

```
> :t decode
decode
  :: FromRecord a =>
     Bool
     -> Data.ByteString.Lazy.Internal.ByteString
     -> Either String (Data.Vector.Vector a)
```

I can't figure out where that random boolean comes from! According to the documentation, it shouldn't be there. This and the import statement were the only things run in this session of ghci.

I'm starting to wonder if I'm losing my mind!

Comment: Can you check which version did you install?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking at the docs for an old version. The one you probably installed is [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/cassava-0.2.2.0/docs/Data-Csv.html). Sometimes google will land you on an old package version; you just have to remember to click "contents" and click through to the version you installed. Also remember to `cabal update`.

Comment: In addition, Bool says whether you have headers or not. I personally don't like this style and would prefer something like data Header = NoHeader | Header.

Comment: @DominicSteinitz It will be `data HasHeader = HasHeader | NoHeader` in the next version.